# i can't make the "game" to stop after 5 wrong words - python

Tags: python, while-loop

just started learning python two days ago
and when I write that code:

```
command = ""
wrong_words_limit = 5
wrong_words_count = 0
started = False
said_already = False

while True:
    command = input("> ").lower()
    wrong_words_count += 1
    if command == "start":
        if started:
            print("Car Is Already Started!")
        else:
            started = True
            print("Car Started...")
    elif command == "stop":
        if not started:
            print("Car Is Already Stopped!")
        else:
            started = False
            print("Car Stopped...")
    elif command == "hello":
        if said_already:
            print("Hey AGAIN ")
        else:
            said_already = True
            print("Hey! :) ")
    elif command == "help":
        print("""
Start - to start the car
Stop - to stop the car
quit - to exit
        """)
    elif command == "quit":
        print("Bye!")
        break
    else:
        while wrong_words_count < 5:
            print("Sorry i don't understand")
            break
```

I want the game to end after **5 wrong words**, like if someone writes - "sksefl"
or something like that 5 times I want the game to end.
what am I doing wrong? I have been on it for the last 2 hours.
thanks!.
(as you can see I tried to do to that at the end of the code)

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) Use a debugger to add breakpoints and step through your code and understand what it's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to do this in the else statement:

```
wrong_words_count += 1
print("Sorry i don't understand")
if wrong_words_count == wrong_words_limit:
     break
```

This adds one to the `wrong_words_count` and then checks if `wrong_words_count` is equal to the limit, and if it is, breaks the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
command = ""
wrong_words_count = 0
started = False
said_already = False

while True:
    if wrong_words_count<5:
      command = input("> ").lower()
    if command == "start":
        if started:
            print("Car Is Already Started!")
        else:
            started = True
            print("Car Started...")
    elif command == "stop":
        if not started:
            print("Car Is Already Stopped!")
        else:
            started = False
            print("Car Stopped...")
    elif command == "hello":
        if said_already:
            print("Hey AGAIN ")
        else:
            said_already = True
            print("Hey! :) ")
    elif command == "help":
        print("""
Start - to start the car
Stop - to stop the car
quit - to exit
        """)
    elif command == "quit":
        print("Bye!")
        break
    elif wrong_words_count==5:
      print("Reached limit. Quitting program...")
      break
    else:
      wrong_words_count += 1
      print("wrong words number: ",wrong_words_count)
```

You can use this code too if you don't want to use wrong_words_limit variable.